# Iframe : Remove iframe scroll and use window scroll to view the content of the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How do you get **Iframe** to disable the scrolling, so it's only the browser that can be used for scrolling? I know you can set `scrolling="no"`, but that is not what I want. If the content exceeds the frame, I want to use the browsers scroll instead of Iframe. How can that be done?

I have different pages with varying heights that'll get populated in the iframe; hence, manually setting height isn't an option. And all the `overflow:hidden` etc have been tried, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle i made.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cx3A3/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <iframe src="http://www.adrianenriquez.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/GbeLD/embedded/result/"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <iframe src="http://www.plusia.it/public/prodotti/6/low/ser-11027-w.jpg"></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, iframe {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.box {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
}
iframe {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

This dynamically/automatically changes the scroll depending on the `<iframe>`'s content.

- Box 1 - X and Y scroll
- Box 2 - Y scroll
- Box 3 - no scroll

Comment: Yeah so, this is what I am trying to avoid..just consider the  adrienenrqiquez iframe; imagine that to be the only iframe present and now if i want to access it in its entirety, i want to use only the page scroll and not the iframe scroll. Automatic adjustment and appearance of the scroll I was able to accomplish, but I don't want the 2 scrolls; I want only the page scroll to access the X and Y's content as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the code you're searching for, but you can create a scrollbar on the right side which is not actually the browser's scrollbar but looks similar.
And, browser's scrollbar can't be used to control elements inside.

However, you can set the the height of the iframe a very large value, so all the pages would fit inside. This will make your page long, enabling browser's scrollbar to scroll the page. :)

Comment: Sigh..I guess that's the only option. I wanted to enable the scrolling of the iframe content via the browser scrollbar alone.

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are on the same domain you can set this page height equals to the iframe's content `scrollHeight`. Set the iframe to a `fixed` position and just mirror the browsers scrolling with jQuery `scroll()` event like this:

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    var h = $('iframe').contents().find('body')[0].scrollHeight;
    $('body').height(h)

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('iframe').contents().find('html, body').scrollTop(winTop);
    });
});
```